# Execute jquery when factory creates a directive dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm modified https://github.com/sachinchoolur/angular-flash to use this instead http://semantic-ui.com/collections/message.html

But the messages are appearing too fast, and I cannot close them. What I want to do is when I create a message from my controller

```
Flash.create('positive', header, message, 0, {class: 'positive', id: 'login-success'}, true);
```

I want to execute jquery before it appears like a fadeIn, and I need to be able to execute this script :

```
$('.message .close')
  .on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.message')
      .transition('fade')
    ;
  });
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo of the same ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/eTectH  I do not understand the error I am getting

Comment: Fixed the plunker, should have a "working" example